# Populate WPF combo box items in XAML style based on the state of another control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I think I'm close, but I'm missing something here.
I'm really trying to stretch my XAML knowledge and unclutter my code behind in my WPF projects.
I have a situation where I'd like to populate the items of a combobox based on the state of another control.

I have a style where I'm checking the value of a checkbox:

```
    <Style 
        x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" 
        TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding ElementName=SomeCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}"
                Value="True">
```

Which seems to allow me to trigger on the value of the box.
I'm trying to figure out how to set up my setter now.
It seems that there is no way to access the items property ...
Here is what I've been messing with:

```
                <Setter
                    Property="Items">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="SomeValue" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

but it's pretty clear that isn't going to work.
Is there a way to do this using the setter?
Do I need to come up with some sort of list or lists that I stow in the window resources and use as an item source?
And how would I make that list?

Comment: Try ItemsSource rather than Items.

Comment: I can user ItemsSource, but I still need to come up with an IEnumerable in the XAML in order to set it.

Comment: Is the list you're trying to populate the ComboBox with a fixed list, or does it change over time?

Comment: It's fixed.  I basically have two different lists of options for the combo box that should be switched in/out as the state of the checkbox changes from checked to unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array declared in your Resources:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <x:Array Type="sys:String" 
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
             x:Key="MyArray">
        <sys:String>One</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Two</sys:String>
    </x:Array>

</Window.Resources>

...

<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" 
       TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SomeCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{StaticResource MyArray}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Beautiful.  Absolutely perfect.  I'd seen the array mentioned elsewhere, but XAML's intellisense didn't want to let me do it so I assumed I was doing something wrong or it wasn't an option for some reason, but I forced it through and everything worked out great.  Thank you for helping me up my XAML game!

Answer (score 2):

> based on the state of another control

I would do it in the code behind on the VM after binding the check box `IsChecked` to a property while also binding the ComboBox's to a list which changes based on the value of `IsChecked`.

Here is a quick example:

```
 public bool IsOperationChecked // Bound to the checkbox
 {                       
     get { return _IsOperationChecked; }
     set { 
            _IsOperationChecked= value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("IsOperationChecked"); 
            Names = (value) ? new List<string>() {"alpha", "beta"} : 
                              new List<string>() {"Bill", "Frank"};
         }
  }

 public List<string> Names // Bound to the Combobox
 {
    get { return _Names; }
    set { _Names = value; OnPropertyChanged("Names"); }
 }
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid doing this in the code behind.  What you've described is absolutely a way to do this, but I'm trying to chalenge myself to figure out a way to do it through XAML.  I'm most of the way there, I just need to create the list in XAML somehow.